# Some PDF documents are messy when printing

Tags: printing, pdf

I have following problem, I've got a PDF document that I need to be printed, but unfortunately, when entering printing preview all characters get messy and they don't resemble original document's content at all. The thing is, this is the only document with such issue I've encountered so far. On Windows, Adobe Reader renders and prints the document just fine.

While I've got this particular document printing problem solved, I'd like to not have to encounter this ever again. I couldn't find anything about this issue.

Here's the document in question, [click here](http://www.speedyshare.com/ag9vG/faktura-11-04-2014.pdf).

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. 
I is only when printing(preview) a pdf. 

example: http://pasteio.com/ih4 (original document here https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet_core_types_cheatsheet.pdf )

Answer (score 5):

Good question. It could be a font issue - the Windows font (Arial) in your document is not installed in Ubuntu by default. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type (or use Ctrl+Shift+V to paste):

```
sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Then press enter. This should install a few common Windows fonts.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced similar problem in case of printing a pdf document. I found that even without printing if I save it as a new .pdf document, I get a document with many misplaced words, unknown symbols and bad spaces. However, I found a solution to this by just saving the original document in .ps format and then converting it using ps2pdf in terminal. The converted output file is exactly same as the original document now and is printable too.